# Sending money to a friend stuck abroad without a debit card?

Tags: europe, money, spain, payment-cards

A friend of mine is stuck in Spain without a debit card, and I'm trying to send her some cash by whatever means available from here in the US. None of the bank branches near her are American, they're all European banks, mostly CaixaBank, Deutsche Bank, and Banc d'España.

She's a dual American/German citizen, and she has both passports with her. She also has a Wells Fargo account, and could even set up a European bank account if needed as a German citizen.

I have accounts with a few American banks (TD Bank, Wells Fargo, etc.), along with cash.

**Is there any way she can walk into a bank in Spain with her passports, with me standing in a bank in the US, and for me to transfer money to her in cash?**

Comment: I am obliged by my conscience to check this is not something that leads to a scam... If not, this is indeed a great question.

Comment: How quick does it need to be?

Comment: @gerrit Same day ideally

Comment: Western Union is great for such situations. Their fee is high but they get the job done in an instant.

Comment: Have you spoken to your friend on the phone and recognized her voice? If not, be wary

Comment: @barbecue Video chat, it’s definitely her, and she’s got two passports proving it

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist, so you're sure that she is herself. I presume that you know her so well that you're either willing to write the money off if it comes to the worst or believe in any promises of repayment.

Comment: Note that the _[Banco de España](https://www.bde.es)_ is the national central bank and the supervisor of the financial entities, but not a bank that offers banking services to individuals, [they themselves warn to distrust people portraying them in such way](https://www.bde.es/bde/en/secciones/servicios/El_Banco_de_Esp_3d9a72d6c1fd821.html).

Comment: If by "without a debit card" you mean her card got lost or stolen, she should call her bank immediately to notify them. She can ask if they have options for an emergency replacement card and/or an emergency cash service. This is common for higher-end credit cards, but it may be possible in other situations. Don't forget to ask about the fees, though.

Comment: Have you ever met this friend? Or this is a cyber friendship? If it is a cyber friend you have never met in person, I still think she's just milking you but of course that's just my opinion.

Comment: How about paypal?

Comment: How exactly she is stuck? From what you write, she still have access to internet, so she can pay flight using her bank account, or she doesn't have the data to do that? US accounts require special device to log in?

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g "US accounts require special device to log in?". I don't think this is related to US, it's the bank that chooses the security measures. All banks I know about (EU banks) require 2FA, let it be OTP token, code card, SMS OTP, app fingerprint, etc. Sometimes **my** bank requires 3FA. It is likely that the OP's friend's bank requires 2FA as well. I will assume she lost or cannot use the token

Comment: Did your "friend" contact you via email? There is a scam exactly with this scenario that has been sent via email with compromised accounts for a decade now.

Comment: PayPal has a service called Xoom, you gotta check which options they have for cash pickup in Spain. Also, there are Western Union in almost every corner in Spain.

Comment: Your friend should talk to her US bank. They will have a relationship with a local Spanish bank to enable emergency cash delivery from her own US account at the Spanish bank. There is no reason for you to be involved unless she has zero money in her US account. This is a perfectly normal procedure.

Comment: @Calchas More info?

Answer (score 47):

I second the comment by B.Liu. *Make really sure this is not a scam.*

I once used Western Union to send money to a relative abroad. They are still in business and so are several other providers. (Andrew mentioned Moneygram in his comment. I'm not suggesting a specific provider based on my limited transactions. Check their websites and FAQs.)

- Your friend might need identity documents. That should be on the site. Back when I used it, all I had to send a number, but since 9/11 things got more stringent.
- Think about a way to make sure if it is really your friend who is asking. Probably less of a problem today if you can skype.

---

PS -- US embassies will provide emergency loans to Americans abroad for repatriation, so if this is a sob story and you have the slightest doubt, refer your friend there. Same for the German embassy.

Comment: I haven't used them much, but I have only good experiences with Western Union. Their agencies often look more like a sleazy money laundring service, but the company is legit enough and their services seem to work reliably. In Spain, Western Union is also represented by the Spanish postal service (Correos), so it should be easy to find an agency nearby.

Comment: We video chatted, and just to be sure I snuck in a few questions only she’d be able to answer and she answered exactly like herself

Comment: Western Union does work well. Of course, the exchange rates are not good, and the expenses are quite high, but the money will become available within minutes. You best go to their website to find the agency closest to your place (it most likely won't be a bank), and also find out where the best place to pick up is for the other person. There are other similar services around; you may check out online. To send and to receive money via WU, you will have to indentify yourself (best with a passport), and they do record your piece of identification.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a scam, but people landing on this page be warned: often your friend is being impersonated. Having said that, I had a good experience with with Moneygram and their fee was half of Western Union's at the time.

Comment: Like the U. S., German embassies will provide assistance to citizens “stranded” abroad. I don’t know the specific means but a loan sounds reasonable.

Comment: The Embassy will only loan you money needed to return to the USA.  From a random (Brazil) [US Embassy page](https://br.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/emergency-financial-assistance/): _Consular officers have no funds available for welfare services because the United States Congress does not provide funds to give or loan to United States citizens in need in foreign countries._ They do say they can help you get home: _If no other resources are available, citizens can apply for a repatriation loan to purchase a one-way ticket directly back to the United States._

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, edited to mention Moneygram.

Comment: @Johnny, edited to reflect the purpose of the loan.

Comment: @Johny and this is exactly what you need to do if you get stuck in foreign country without money. Return to your country and get back the credentials to your bank account.

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g - I think that depends a lot on the purpose of your journey. If you're a 20 year old backpacking across Europe and someone steals your backpack with all of your money, then getting cash from family/friends to continue the journey sounds reasonable. If you're a 70 year old that just got beaten and robbed, then maybe getting home is the better course of action. But just losing your money isn't necessarily a reason to end the trip.

Comment: @Johnny, don't forget the 20-year-old backpacker who would really like to make another side trip and needs just a little bit of cash from mom and dad. International money transfers have gotten easier in recent decades, but there are places where cash by something like WU or Moneygram fits in.

Comment: This question wouldn't exist if it was a scam.  It's highly unlikely that a scammer is going to ask for money and not recommend a method to transmit it.

Comment: @PrimeException, it seems that the OP is quite sure that this is not a scam. Other people googling this answer might need to be reminded to check.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what has already been said (and I second the Western Union or Moneygram option if you are 100% sure it's not a scam), if your friend's cards were stolen or lost, she could also ask for assistance from her travel insurance (of course, provided she has travel insurance - sometimes some debit/credit cards have this for the holder, under certain conditions - and it covers these kinds of situations).

Depending on the coverage they even go so far as to get their local offices to give you cash.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to send Bitcoin, which arrives in minutes.

Your friend can get cash from a Bitcoin ATM 24/7, without dealing with a person and normally without any identification.

Have your friend go to a BTC ATM and complete the process to withdraw cash, have them send you a picture of the QR code, you send the BTC directly to the ATM using the QR code, and your friend will have the cash in minutes.

Comment: Do you have an address of one in Spain? Because I have never ever seen one.

Comment: There are many.  See https://coinatmradar.com/country/199/bitcoin-atm-spain/ but always verify in person.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  The answer is good one, and avoids a number of practical issues (especially the requirement for identification), and is usable as long as you have a secure method of communication (so that you can be sure the recipient isn't being impersonated) and they are in a location where the facility is available.

Comment: How do I buy/find/convert money to bitcoins? I have never had to deal with them and do not understand how easy or hard it will be.

Comment: The fastest way is by going to a Bitcoin ATM to buy the coins if you have an ATM nearby and meeting someone in person from https://localbitcoins.com if not.  The safest way is https://coinbase.com but they may hold your money for a few days, depending on how risky their system thinks you are.  You can send bitcoins directly from one ATM to the other with QR codes.  You should do more research if you use this method because you can lose your money if it's not done properly.

Comment: It is really convenient to do this actually but it may take some learning/set up time to feel safe using it. I have a coinbase at bitstamp account in Germany and can receive bitcoin/litecoin/eth from family abroad and convert it to cash. Usually the money is in my bank account the next day, sometimes it can take 2 days.

Comment: Are BTC transactions really guaranteed to complete within few minutes? I have heard horror stories about them being stuck for hours due to some global limit of amount of transactions concurrently running. Standing in front of ATM waiting for it to clear for more than 1-2 minutes might be tricky.

Comment: You decide how fast it clears depending on the transaction fee that you pay. It's your choice.  Most ATMs print a receipt with the QR code to send the coins to and you can come back hours later and scan the receipt.

Comment: @PrimeException as idea sounds good, but i wouldn't say it's many of them. based on your link, there is around 40 of them in spain which is far from many. btw what are the charges for buying and selling BTC?

Comment: @user902383 It depends on the ATM, but less than a corporate transmitter.  Some charge commission and others have the fees in the exchange rates.  The fees are similar to any currency exchange company. You can also find people on LocalBitcoins if there is not an ATM nearby.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the amount of money being sent, and the time period in which it is needed, if you both already have a money sharing/payment application setup such as Venmo, PayPal, Google Wallet, etc; you can send her money, have her transfer it to her bank, and then walk into the bank and withdraw it.

If you both have Wells Fargo, it might be easiest to work with them, though again, this will likely take several (business) days. However, you can transfer money to your friend's Wells Fargo account, and then she can add a local (German) bank account and transfer the money there. 
https://www.wellsfargo.com/online-banking/transfers/

The other option may be a mobile check deposit to a local (German) bank and again, after several days of it clearing will be available for withdrawal.

Overall, if the timeline doesn't matter as much, and she just needs it within the next week or so, then there are a few ways of doing it for free. However, if expediency/ease is of importance here, then a wire is likely your best bet, though you'll definitely pay for the convenience, and there are some other great answers to this end.

Answer (score 2):

If she has a few days to set things up, using a prepaid debit card is possibly the most cost-effective way.  It's easy to pick up a card in most places in Europe, and a lot of cards can be directly topped up from another credit or debit card.  The only problem is that in order to accept top-ups from another card, she may need to prove identity and address, which may be difficult for a non EU citizen, and the process of approval may take a day or two.  It may however also be possible to use a bank transfer to top up the card (to a certain limit) without proof of identity; this is something you'd need to check with individual card issuers.

The fees for this service are usually much lower than those for traditional money transfer services.